# ROS2 in Docker on Mac M1 (Sonoma) not able to publish topic to outside machines

Tags: ros-humble, docker, networking

I'm testing an ROS2 (Humble) installation on a Mac M1 running the Sonoma OS. The Dockerfile is using arm64v8/ros:humble-perception-jammy. I also added the demo nodes (cpp talker and listener).

In my Dockerfile I set these env vars:

```
ENV RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
ENV ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1
```

After building, I can start a container from the image (the image id is 0dd755bb6247):

```
docker run -it 0dd755bb6247
```

Then from the running container I can ping outside computers. I can run

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_py talker
```

and this is running:

```
[INFO] [1698865202.013626343] [talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 0
[INFO] [1698865202.989864769] [talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 1"
...
```

but on a different machine ROS2 cannot see the topic being published (/chatter).

I also tried setting up a custom network:

```
docker network create my_custom_network
```

and opening up all ports I believe ROS2 uses in docker-compose.yaml:

```
enter version: '3'

networks:
  my_custom_network:
    name: my_custom_network
    external: true
default:
  external:
    name: my_custom_network
services:
  test:
    image: busterbot/ros:buster
    command: ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
    networks:
      - my_custom_network
    ports:
      - "32650:32650"
      - "32651:32651"
      - "32660:32660"
      - "32661:32661"
      - "32662:32662"
      - "32663:32663"
      - "11811:11811"
      - "11812:11812"
```

Also, I am using OrbStack for the Docker GUI.

I'm not sure it matters but ifconfig in the running container results in

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.215.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.215.255
```

Where the Mac's IP is 192.168.1.100. Also, the firewall on the Mac is off.

I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can try to fix this -

1. Check if you can `ros2 topic echo /<your_topic_name>` on the same machine outside the container. If not, set the domain ID to be 1.
2. Make sure if you're using `--net=host` to allow Docker access to host network resources. Mac doesn't allow it unfortunately, so refer to the individual port exposing [in this ROS answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/374042/nodes-cant-talk-to-host-when-running-ros2-in-docker-on-macos/)
3. Did you `export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1` to the other computers on the network too?
4. See that you're using the right network interface for DDS communication, [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/373132/how-to-specify-the-network-interface-ros2-uses-for-communication/) might help. Make sure you're using the same DDS vendor on all systems.
5. I have had a range of issues with fast RTPS, try [cyclone DDS](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/DDS-Implementations/Working-with-Eclipse-CycloneDDS.html).